# Unit tests for Graphics or FE boxes

Tags: graphics, front-end, error-tracking, testing-and-verification

Consider the following expression with bad syntax:

```
Graphics[{foo}]
```

[image]

How can I detect the error and retrieve the error message programmatically, so I can check for it in unit tests?

Comment: A poor man's equivalent: [Testing Framework applications in the FrontEnd area](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118547/5478)

Comment: related: [29086](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29086/5478) and related option: `HighlightFormattingErrors`

Comment: Lacking a better solution, what I have done is wrapping my test with Hash[] and comparing with the expected value.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino `Hash` only works so far, and is very brittle to innocuous changes to the `Graphics` structure, e.g. this sort of shift is not uncommon: `Graphics[{primitives}, opts]` to `Graphics[{{primitives}}, opts]`, and it does nothing to the end state. Other than FE error detection, if you are comparing `Graphics` objects, the only meaningful comparison is their end states, i.e. you need a [parser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been partially answered before, so here I will highlight some of its evolution since that [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29108/52). `VerificationTest` and its `` MUnit` `` antecedents do not have a mechanism for introducing new error types, so we need a function to do that for us. For this, I use a function called `checkGraphicsRendering` (outlined at the end) with the general use being the two argument form, as follows

```
VerificationTest[
  checkGraphicsRendering[
    testFunction
    ,
    expressionToTest
  ]
  ,
  {testResult, "RenderingErrors" -> {FEError ...}}
  ,
  testOptions
]
```

where `testFunction` operates on the result of `expressionToTest` generating `testResult` while simultaneously checking the FrontEnd for any `FEError`s (pink boxes). When there are a large number of tests with identical `testFunction`s, I will usually set

```
checkGraphicsRendering`$defaultTest = testFunction
```

so that I can employ the one argument form. Additionally, there are some cases where executing `expressionToTest` within a notebook is essential, e.g. checking that `PlotTheme -> Automatic` picks up the stylesheet theme, so there are two options for `checkGraphicsRendering`: `"NotebookEvaluate"` which takes boolean values and `"NotebookOptions"` which are passed to `CreateDocument` and default to `` checkGraphicsRendering`$defaultNotebookOptions ``. So, if you want to have additional options in addition to the default, just use

```
"NotebookOptions" -> {opts ..., checkGraphicsRendering`$defaultNotebookOptions}
```

and they will be flattened out internally. Lastly, when dealing with automatically generated tests, I generally alter the output of `checkGraphicsRendering` to

```
Hold[expressionToTest] -> {testResult, "RenderingErrors" -> {FEError ...}}
```

as it allows the user to simply execute what expression the test actually ran.

---

Here I will discuss the package itself. As mentioned above, there are two user settable constants: `$defaultNotebookOptions` and `$defaultTest` which the package checks prior to setting the default, so they are not overridden. Usually, I set the `NotebookFileName` as you do not need to have a notebook named `Untitled-2045` when run from the FE, but it comes with a drawback: the notebook is created on disk. So, I often find `FEMessages.nb` notebooks scattered all over the place. The most important note, though, is `NotebookEvaluate` does not work when the FE is not the `$ParentLink`. So, I workaround this by `Block`ing `$ParentLink` when needed.

```
BeginPackage["checkGraphicsRendering`"];

checkGraphicsRendering;
$defaultNotebookOptions;
$defaultTest;

Begin["`Private`"];
ClearAll[checkGraphicsRendering, linkedNotebookEvaluate];
SetAttributes[checkGraphicsRendering, HoldAll];

$defaultNotebookOptions = If[ValueQ@$defaultNotebookOptions,
  $defaultNotebookOptions, 
  {Visible -> False, NotebookFileName -> "FEMessages.nb"}
];

$defaultTest = If[ValueQ@$defaultTest, $defaultTest, Identity];

Options[checkGraphicsRendering] := {"NotebookEvaluate" -> False, 
   "NotebookOptions" :> $defaultNotebookOptions};

linkedNotebookEvaluate[expr_] := 
 If[$Linked && Cases[$FrontEnd, _LinkObject, -1] =!= {$ParentLink}
   , 
   Block[{$ParentLink}, NotebookEvaluate[expr, InsertResults->True]]
   , 
   NotebookEvaluate[expr, InsertResults->True]
];

checkGraphicsRendering[test_, expr_, OptionsPattern[]]:=
Block[{nb, res, pinks, evalFlag},
  evalFlag= TrueQ@OptionValue["NotebookEvaluate"];
  UsingFrontEnd[
    nb = CreateDocument[
      If[evalFlag
        ,
        ExpressionCell[Defer[expr], "Input"]
        ,
        ExpressionCell[res = expr, "Output"]
      ]
      , 
      ##
    ]& @@ Flatten[{OptionValue["NotebookOptions"]}]; 
    res = If[evalFlag, linkedNotebookEvaluate[nb], res];
    SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];
    pinks = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`GetErrorsInSelectionPacket[nb]];
    NotebookClose[nb]
  ];
  {test@res, "Rendering Errors" -> pinks}
]

checkGraphicsRendering[expr:Except[_?OptionQ], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
  checkGraphicsRendering[$defaultTest, expr, opts]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful!  Regarding the `$ParentLink` problem, also very useful. I asked about it here and even WRI people couldn't answer: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/971065  Perhaps you could post an answer there too. BTW this problem with EvaluateNotebook does not seem to be present in 10.3 and later.

Comment: @Szabolcs I discovered it quite by accident, trying to run tests within WB. I'll look at it again, but I'm fairly sure it still exists in some form.

Comment: @Szabolcs: `NotebookEvaluate` when run in a standalone or sub-kernel is fraught with issues. We've run into them internally when creating new testing tools. The FE devs tell us that this is a very tricky problem to solve.