# How to capture implicit fails in Plot or Show?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, debugging

How can I make a construct similar to C++ functions:

```
try{} catch{}
```

I want to use it to avoid showing a lot of errors in the plot area when for example one of the arguments becomes complex or overflows etc. I want to avoid of creating a plot if ANYTHING goes wrong, so it does not look like the one below:

```
Show@Graphics[Line[{{Complex[1, 1]}, {Complex[2, 2]}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Approaches like:

```
Check[Show[Graphics[Line[{{Complex[1, 1]}, {Complex[2, 2]}}]]], Show[Graphics[{}]]]
```

or

```
Check[Graphics[Line[{{Complex[1, 1]}, {Complex[2, 2]}}]], Show[Graphics[{}]]
```

also fail.

Comment: Is `Check` useful?

Comment: I have tried, but it still plots that way, or maybe I am doing something wrong: `Check[Show[Graphics[Line[{{Complex[1, 1]}, {Complex[2, 2]}}]]], 
 Show[Graphics[{}]]]` or `Check[Graphics[Line[{{Complex[1, 1]}, {Complex[2, 2]}}]], 
 Show[Graphics[{}]]]`

Comment: Oh well, it was a good try. Perhaps add this into your question...?

Comment: `Check` will only catch kernel messages. The pink boxes you see are formatting errors generated by the front end. Have a look at rcollyer's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29108/862) for a way to check for these errors.

Comment: Try `Catch[]` :)

Comment: @Zet I fail to see how `Catch` would work here: clearly, the last examples of OP show that the problem is that **no explicit error message is generated** during evaluating the expression but the result is still wrong. So how to capture such an implicit failure? I have no idea, but it is a good question.

Comment: @Misery I've simplified your question (hope you don't mind it) perhaps it attracts more people who can help you out.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Fine, I hope it will be more useful for others. Regards :]

Comment: Note: despite the close vote, I still upvoted this. I think it is a good question, well phrased, and a good entry point for the duplicate question.