# Is there a GraphicsPrimitiveQ (or a complete list of Heads of graphics primitives)?

Tags: graphics, function-construction, pattern-matching, expression-test, argument-patterns

For various reasons related to workflow associated with creating figures for journals, I am creating functions that will accept graphics primitives and a set of options and spit out a `Graphics` object with those primitives and those options in some configuration.

(Of course, this sounds like all I'm doing is re-creating `Graphics`, in that I can call

```
Graphics[ <List of primitives>, <Sequence of options>]
```

but it's more complicated than that.)

In any case, I would like to be able to check whether the inputs to the function are graphics primitives or not. We can create our own `GraphicsPrimitiveQ` if we have a list of the `Head`s of graphics primitives. For instance,

```
Clear[GraphicsPrimitiveQ, listOfHeads]
listOfHeads = {Line, Polygon, Point, Arrow, Tube};
GraphicsPrimitiveQ[x_] := MatchQ[Head[x], Alternatives @@ listOfHeads]
```

in which case if we define

```
f[x__?GraphicsPrimitiveQ] := {x}
```

then

```
f[Point[{0, 0}], Line[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}}]]
(* {Point[{0, 0}], Line[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}}} *)
```

and

```
f[Point[{0, 0}], 1]
(* f[Point[{0, 0}], 1] *)
```

- So: **Is there something like a GraphicsPrimitiveQ?**
- Or: **Is there hidden somewhere in Mathematica an easy way to get a list of all graphics primitives?**
- Alternatively, if there's no built-in `ListOfGraphicsPrimitives[]`, then **Is there a programmatic way of making the function `GraphicsPrimitiveQ`?** (Added this because I for some reason didn't anticipate the clever answers below.)

Comment: Here's a [parser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52) I wrote for work. It has an almost complete list of primitives and directives. All that it is missing is the new stuff for 10.2.

Comment: @rcollyer. I saw this answer in my search before posting the question! I was hoping for something that could be called directly from Mathematica, but I can always deposit your `primitives` in a package if I need to. Thanks!

Comment: I think I have something that will work, programatically.

Comment: In the old days, I had to maintain a long list based on the list given in the docs. I like this question; maybe you should also ask about the possibility of a `GraphicsDirectiveQ[]`. :)

Comment: @march correction, now the parser has a complete list of primitives. I forgot to add the v10 and v10.2 primitives even in my local implementation.

Answer (score 22):

**Edit**: It was pointed out that the original form is not bullet-proof, e.g. `GraphicsPrimitiveQ /@ {InputNotebook, Unique, Sequence}` all returned `True`. However, when looking upon this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27209/52) about generating new graphics primitives, a superior answer came to light:

```
Clear[GraphicsPrimitiveQ];
GraphicsPrimitiveQ[s_Symbol | (s_)[___]] := 
 0 < Count[DownValues[Typeset`MakeBoxes], 
   Verbatim[HoldPattern][HoldPattern[Typeset`MakeBoxes[s[___], __, Graphics]]], -1]
```

which is now bullet-proof:

```
GraphicsPrimitiveQ /@ {Rectangle, Pyramid, Sequence}
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

I need to look deeper for one dealing with `Graphics3D`, though.

---

This is the old version. It works, but has issues.

This works for `Graphics` primitives:

```
Clear[GraphicsPrimitiveQ];
GraphicsPrimitiveQ[s_Symbol] := !MatchQ[ToBoxes@Graphics[s[]], GraphicsBox[_s]]


GraphicsPrimitiveQ /@ {Line, Bob, CapsuleShape (*3d primitive*)}
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

with the additional rule

```
GraphicsPrimitiveQ[e : (h_)[___]] := !MatchQ[ToBoxes@Graphics[e], GraphicsBox[_h]]

GraphicsPrimitiveQ[#[{{1,2},{3,4}}]]& /@ {Polygon, List}
(* {True, False} *)
```

This works because in the presence of `Graphics`, the primitives have a box form, e.g.

```
ToBoxes@Graphics@Line[{{1,2},{3,4}}]
(* GraphicsBox@LineBox[{{1,2},{3,4}}] *)
```

but non-primitives do not, even those that have box forms

```
ToBoxes@Subscript[x, 2]
(* SubscriptBox[x, 2] *)

ToBoxes@Graphics@Subscript[x, 2]
(* GraphicsBox[Subscript[x, 2]] *)
```

nor do primitives expand to their box form outside of `Graphics`, e.g.

```
ToBoxes@Line[]
(* RowBox[{"Line", "[", "]"}] *)
```

---

We can do the same with `Graphics3D`,

```
Clear[GraphicsPrimitiveQ];
Graphics3DPrimitiveQ[s_Symbol] := 
   !MatchQ[ToBoxes@Graphics3D[s[]], Graphics3DBox[_s]]
Graphics3DPrimitiveQ[e : (h_)[___]] := 
   !MatchQ[ToBoxes@Graphics3D[e], Graphics3DBox[_h]]
```

but it returns `True` for exclusively 2D primitives, e.g.

```
Graphics3DPrimitiveQ @ Rectangle
(* True *)
```

So, I do not know how to approach this, if you want something that will exclusively detect 3D primitives.

Comment: That's... mysterious. I'll try to parse that later. In the meantime, +1. (I'm out of votes for the day, but I'll upvote in a couple of hours.) I will need it to find 3D primitives, in general. Also, in order to match the primitive and not just the `Head`, could we do instead `GraphicsPrimitiveQ[s_Symbol[__]]`?

Comment: That's fine! All I wanted was the all-in-one package. I don't need 3D exclusively. Thanks again!

Comment: It was a guess, an educated guess, but a guess nonetheless, and I got lucky. :)

Comment: I like the idea but there is a potential problem:  `GraphicsPrimitiveQ /@ {InputNotebook, Unique, Sequence}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well, it's a good thing I found a better way. I'll post it shortly, I hope.

Comment: I'm afraid your new method is far from "bullet-proof:"  `GraphicsPrimitiveQ /@ {Polygon, Disk, Circle}` :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I noticed that last night. There are several instances of primitives that do not have `Graphics` as their third argument, like `Circle` which has `_`. So, `Graphics` applies to it, but it is a bit squirrelly. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Using your own list of primitives from [(32719)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/121) reveals that `GraphicsPrimitiveQ` fails more often that it succeeds.  In 10.1.0 failures are: `{AASTriangle, ASATriangle, BezierCurve, BSplineCurve, BSplineSurface, Circle, Circumsphere, Cone, Cylinder, Disk, EmptyRegion, FullRegion, Hexahedron, Parallelepiped, Parallelogram, Polygon, Prism, Pyramid, Raster, Raster3D, SASTriangle, SSSTriangle, Tetrahedron, Tube}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `AASTriangle`, etc., should be removed from that list as they evaluate to `Triangle` via `DownValues`. `BSplineSurface` is actually a uniquely 3D primitive that works; who knew? The two regions were a mistake. This is going to require some fiddling.

Comment: You'll notice the conspicuous lack of an answer from me.  Happy fiddling! ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've even considered using `RegionQ`, but alas no `DownValues` to query.

Comment: I decided to post the only simple answer I can think of.  It's not a good match for what the OP requested but I think it has potentially useful behavior of its own.  I expect you'll inform me of its failings. :-)

Comment: Would checking the dimensions of arrays within primitives be good enough to distinguish 2D from 3D?

Answer (score 11):

With `WolframLanguageData` your list of graphics primitives will stay up to date.

```
ListOfGraphicsPrimitives[] = Symbol /@ 
 WolframLanguageData[
  EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea","GraphicsPrimitiveFunctions"}], "Name"]
```

> {AASTriangle, AffineHalfSpace, AffineSpace, Annulus, Arrow, 
>   ASATriangle, Ball, BezierCurve, BSplineCurve, CapsuleShape, Circle, 
>   Circumsphere, Cone, ConicHullRegion, Cuboid, Cylinder, Disk, 
>   DiskSegment, Ellipsoid, EmptyRegion, FilledCurve, FullRegion, 
>   GraphicsComplex, HalfLine, HalfPlane, HalfSpace, Hexahedron, 
>   Hyperplane, Insphere, JoinedCurve, Line, Parallelepiped, 
>   Parallelogram, Point, Polygon, Prism, Rectangle, RegularPolygon, 
>   SASTriangle, Simplex, Sphere, SphericalShell, SSSTriangle, 
>   StadiumShape, Tetrahedron, Triangle, Tube}

```
ListOfGraphicsFunctions[] = Symbol /@ 
 WolframLanguageData[
  EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea","GraphicsFunctions"}], "Name"]
```

> {AbsoluteDashing, AbsolutePointSize, AbsoluteThickness, Antialiasing, 
>   Arrowheads, AspectRatio, Axes, AxesEdge, AxesLabel, AxesOrigin, 
>   AxesStyle, Axis, Back, Background, BezierFunction, 
>   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics, Boxed, BoxRatios, BoxStyle, 
>   BSplineFunction, BSplineSurface, CapForm, ClippingStyle, ClipPlanes, 
>   ClipPlanesStyle, ClipRange, ContentSelectable, ContourLabels, 
>   Contours, ContourShading, CoordinatesToolOptions, CurveClosed, 
>    Dashing[{Small, 
>      Small}], Dashing, DataRange, DataReversed, DateTicksFormat, 
>   DefaultAxesStyle, DefaultBaseStyle, DefaultBoxStyle, 
>   DefaultFaceGridsStyle, DefaultFrameStyle, DefaultFrameTicksStyle, 
>   Directive, DiscretizeGraphics, DisplayFunction, 
>    Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}], 
>    Dashing[{0, 
>      Small}], EdgeForm, Epilog, Exclusions, ExtentElementFunction, 
>   ExtentMarkers, ExtentSize, FaceGrids, Filling, FillingStyle, Frame, 
>   FrameLabel, FrameMargins, FrameTicks, Front, FullGraphics, Graphics, 
>   Graphics3D, GraphicsColumn, GraphicsGrid, GraphicsGroup, GraphicsRow, 
>   GridLines, Inset, ItemAspectRatio, Joined, Lighting, LightingAngle, 
>   Mesh, MeshFunctions, MeshShading, NCache, NormalsFunction, Offset, 
>   Opacity, OpacityFunction, OpacityFunctionScaling, PixelConstrained, 
>   PointSize, PolarAxes, PolarAxesOrigin, PolarGridLines, PolarTicks, 
>   Prolog, Raster, Raster3D, Rasterize, RasterSize, RegionFunction, 
>   RevolutionAxis, Rotate, RotateLabel, RotationAction, RoundingRadius, 
>   Scale, Scaled, Show, Specularity, SphericalRegion, SplineClosed, 
>   SplineDegree, SplineKnots, SplineWeights, StreamScale, Texture, 
>    Thickness[Large], Thickness, 
>    Thickness[Tiny], Ticks, Translate, GrayLevel[
>    0, 0], VertexColors, VertexDataCoordinates, VertexNormals, 
>   VertexTextureCoordinates, ViewAngle, ViewCenter, ViewMatrix, 
>   ViewPoint, ViewRange, ViewVector, ViewVertical}

Hop this helps.

Comment: I tried to get this yesterday, but I think I will need a lot of time till I get intuition how to work entities :-/

Comment: On my Mac with v11.3, `ListOfGraphicsPrimitives` gives me different results than shown here and does not include the following primitives listed in the documentation for [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html): Disk, **InfiniteLine**, **Inset**, **GraphicsGroup**, Line, **Locator**, Point, Polygon, **Raster**, SASTriangle, and **Text**. The bolded entries are also not in your results.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question depends upon what exactly should be called as "graphics primitive". In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) from the practical point of view I define it as a container which can be found inside of `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`, which draws something and is not a graphical directive or `Dynamic` wrapper. This definition differs from the usual meaning but covers all the key cases. Here is (I hope) complete list of such containers for version 10.2:

> {Point, PointBox, Line, LineBox, Arrow, ArrowBox, Rectangle, RectangleBox, Parallelogram, Triangle, JoinedCurve, JoinedCurveBox, FilledCurve, FilledCurveBox, StadiumShape, DiskSegment, Annulus, BezierCurve, BezierCurveBox, BSplineCurve, BSplineCurveBox, BSplineSurface, BSplineSurface3DBox, SphericalShell, CapsuleShape, Raster, RasterBox, Raster3D, Raster3DBox, Polygon, PolygonBox, RegularPolygon, Disk, DiskBox, Circle, CircleBox, Sphere, SphereBox, Ball, Ellipsoid, Cylinder, CylinderBox, Tetrahedron, TetrahedronBox, Cuboid, CuboidBox, Parallelepiped, Hexahedron, HexahedronBox, Prism, PrismBox, Pyramid, PyramidBox, Simplex, ConicHullRegion, ConicHullRegionBox, Hyperplane, HalfSpace, AffineHalfSpace, AffineSpace, ConicHullRegion3DBox, Cone, ConeBox, InfiniteLine, InfinitePlane, HalfLine, InfinitePlane, HalfPlane, Tube, TubeBox, GraphicsComplex, GraphicsComplexBox, GraphicsGroup, GraphicsGroupBox, GeoGraphics, Graphics, GraphicsBox, Graphics3D, Graphics3DBox, MeshRegion, BoundaryMeshRegion, GeometricTransformation, GeometricTransformationBox, Rotate, Translate, Scale, SurfaceGraphics, Text, TextBox, Inset, InsetBox, Inset3DBox, Panel, PanelBox, Legended, Placed, LineLegend, Texture}

Answer (score 7):

Since there seems no other simple answer at this time I propose the approach of rendering a `Graphics` expression and seeing if it has errors.  By definition this will pass both primitives and directives, as well as inert expressions such as `{}`.  I hope it nevertheless serves some purpose.

I rasterize the graphic and look for the tell-tale pink warning color.  Of course it would be easy to create a false negative simply by creating an element with this very color but that is a corner case.

```
graphicsQ = 
  FreeQ[Union @@ ImageData @ Image[Graphics[#], ImageSize -> 30], 
    x_ /; x == {1.`, 0.9019607843137255`, 0.9019607843137255`}] &;
```

Positive examples:

```
graphicsQ /@ {Thick, Green, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2, 1}], Red, Disk[], Blue, Circle[{2, 0}],
   Yellow, Polygon[{{2, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, -1}}], Purple, Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}], Black, Dashed, Line[{{-1, 0}, {4, 0}}]}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

Some negative examples:

```
graphicsQ /@ {Circle["x"], Arrow[], Line[], Pi, 2.2}
```

> {False, False, False, False, False}

Specifically I included malformed primitives to demonstrate that these are not passed.  This may or may not be desirable depending on your application.

Comment: The pink color works, but I think the superior method is to adapt this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29108/52), and yes this was my ultimate fall back method.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm sad to say I forgot about that answer!  Would you like to post a second answer using that method and I shall delete mine?

Comment: I'll might do that this afternoon. I might edit yours. Neither will happen until this afternoon. :P

Comment: I think the fact that it outputs `False` for malformed primitives (something that I didn't think of) is extremely useful, for a number of reasons, so this is a good addition.