# Display position of expression as Tooltip

Tags: expression-manipulation, tooltip

How could we display the position of any sub expression in an expression using `Tooltip`?

This would be useful for example in order to locate the position of an element in the `FullForm` of a `Plot`.

I think I saw a similar Q&A once, but I haven't found it again.

**Edit**

The answer of Kuba is very instructive. Here is the function I had in mind which is a variation of Kuba's answer.

```
labelPositions[graphics_] := Fold[Function[{plot, pos}, MapAt[Tooltip[#, pos] &, plot, pos]], graphics, Position[graphics,_,Infinity]]
```

Using Kuba's comment, even simpler

```
labelPositions[graphics_]:= MapIndexed[Tooltip,graphics,Infinity, Heads -> True]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the position"?  Please give a specific example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have to use [Is there a GraphicsPrimitiveQ (or a complete list of Heads of graphics primitives)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88549/5478)

```
primitivesQ = MatchQ[#, 
    Alternatives @@ {Point, PointBox, Line, LineBox, Arrow, ArrowBox,           Rectangle, RectangleBox, Parallelogram, Triangle, JoinedCurve,           JoinedCurveBox, FilledCurve, FilledCurveBox, StadiumShape,           DiskSegment, Annulus, BezierCurve, BezierCurveBox, BSplineCurve,           BSplineCurveBox, BSplineSurface, BSplineSurface3DBox,           SphericalShell, CapsuleShape, Raster, RasterBox, Raster3D,           Raster3DBox, Polygon, PolygonBox, RegularPolygon, Disk, DiskBox,           Circle, CircleBox, Sphere, SphereBox, Ball, Ellipsoid,           Cylinder, CylinderBox, Tetrahedron, TetrahedronBox, Cuboid,           CuboidBox, Parallelepiped, Hexahedron, HexahedronBox, Prism,           PrismBox, Pyramid, PyramidBox, Simplex, ConicHullRegion,           ConicHullRegionBox, Hyperplane, HalfSpace, AffineHalfSpace,           AffineSpace, ConicHullRegion3DBox, Cone, ConeBox, InfiniteLine,           InfinitePlane, HalfLine, InfinitePlane, HalfPlane, Tube, 
      TubeBox, GraphicsComplex, GraphicsComplexBox, GraphicsGroup,           GraphicsGroupBox, GeoGraphics, Graphics, GraphicsBox,           Graphics3D, Graphics3DBox, MeshRegion, BoundaryMeshRegion,           GeometricTransformation, GeometricTransformationBox, Rotate,           Translate, Scale, SurfaceGraphics, Text, TextBox, Inset,           InsetBox, Inset3DBox, Panel, PanelBox, Legended, Placed,           LineLegend, Texture}
    ] &;
```

---

#### code

```
labelPositions[graphics_] := Fold[
  Function[{plot, pos}, 
   MapAt[Tooltip[#, Column@{Head[#], pos}] &, plot, pos]],
  graphics,
  Position[graphics, x_[___] /; primitivesQ[x], \[Infinity]]
  ]
```

#### test

```
plot = Graphics[{Thick, Green, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2, 1}], Red, 
    Disk[], Blue, Circle[{2, 0}], Yellow, 
    Polygon[{{2, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, -1}}], Purple, Arrowheads[Large], 
    Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}], Black, Dashed, 
    Line[{{-1, 0}, {4, 0}}]}];


labelPositions @ plot
```

[image]

### todo

This is done with an assumption that primitives are not nested within others. In general that's not true, like for `FilledCurve @ BSplineCurve[...]` so those cases should be handled with more care.

Comment: This is very impressive. I modified your function to suit what I wanted, ie to get the position of any component of an expression represented in FullForm: labelPositions[graphics_] := 
 Fold[Function[{plot, pos}, MapAt[Tooltip[#, pos] &, plot, pos]], 
  graphics, Position[graphics, x_, Infinity]]

Comment: I realized with your answer, it would be quite practical if MapAt had the position in #2 as argument similarly to MapIndexed. Maybe one day, or maybe not, as maybe this could have an impact on performance, I don't know.

Comment: @faysou yep, but what about: `MapIndexed[If[#2[[-1]] == 0, Tooltip[##], #] &,
 
 plot , {1, \[Infinity]}, Heads -> True]`

Comment: Looks good ! Thanks