# A list of Graphics Primitives

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

**Is it possible to programmatically get a list of 2D and/or 3D Graphics Primitives?**

Edit: Indeed, there is an answer to this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88342/is-there-a-graphicsprimitiveq-or-a-complete-list-of-heads-of-graphics-primitive). It is, however, much focused on a function checking that the object is a primitive, then on the one giving a list of such.

There is a list of primitives in the answer of A. Popkov. Not a function as I asked, however. Its disadvantage is that it is related to the 10.3 version and does not communicate what happened since.

In the answer of Edmund, there is a function that must return a list of primitives. On Mma 11.2 it only returns a part of primitives. For example, such a primitive as Point is missing for me, though it is present in the original answer of Edmund.

I conclude that no satisfactory answer to my question still exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Is there a GraphicsPrimitiveQ (or a complete list of Heads of graphics primitives)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88342/280)"

Comment: If you look "Graphics Objects" into the documentation center, then you will get all Graphics primitives and directives.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question specifically asks for "Is it possible to programmatically get a list of 2D and/or 3D Graphics Primitives?".