# Obtain complete list of built-in graphical objects, and split them into groups?

Tags: graphics, curated-data, symbols, language-design, entity

I would like to obtain the complete listing of built-in graphical objects (which can be used in `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`) available in Wolfram Language, split into several groups.

The first group should include basic graphical primitives such as `Point`, `Line`, `HalfLine`, `Disk`, `DiskSegment`, `Annulus`, `StadiumShape`, `Cube`, etc.

The second group should include such composite primitives as `JoinedCurve` and `FilledCurve` (I do not know other such composite primitives, but may be I missed some?).

The third group should include such symbols as `GraphicsGroup` and `GraphicsComplex`, which intended to represent collections of primitives.

The fourth group should include such symbols as `GeometricTransformation`, `Rotate` and `Translate`, which intended to apply some geometric transformations to collections of primitives.

The fifth group should include symbols related to dynamic interactivity such as `Dynamic`, `Tooltip`, `Mouseover`, etc.

For each symbol I would like to obtain the following properties:

1. Corresponding box form symbol (if it is different for 2D and 3D graphics, I wish to list both).
2. Is it intended to be used in `Graphics`, `Graphics3D`, or both?

**How can I do this programmatically (using the `Entity` framework or by other means)?** I'm most interested in the first two groups.

---

The following question is strongly related, but the answers to it do not fully answer the question posed:

- [Is there a GraphicsPrimitiveQ (or a complete list of Heads of graphics primitives)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88342/280)

Comment: for the first one `WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "FunctionalityAreas" -> ContainsAll[{"GraphicsPrimitiveSymbols"}]]]`?

Comment: and for the second thru fourth `WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "FunctionalityAreas" -> ContainsAll[{"GraphicsSymbols"}]]]`?

Comment: @kglr It is surprizing, but your fist code doesn't return `Point`, `Line`, `Polygon`, `Disk` and some other basic primitives...

Comment: @kglr Your second code returns (for the most part) a list of *options* related to graphic functions, not the primitives themselves.